# Create my own Google site template Using my own CSS

Tags: html, css, google-apps, google-sites

Is there a way to create my custom Google site using my own CSS code? I have tried putting `<style>` but google won't allow me. I can use several inline CSS, but i have noticed that some CSS are not allowed too. e.g `position:absolute;`

I'm asking this because i can see some websites selling Google site templates. How did they manage to do those template? What language are they using? Is there some sort of software that  does it?

Comment: Hmm didn't see that when i searched, Anyway Thanks, that answered my question.

Answer (score -2):

Create a [code block](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en/). This allows you to put HTML/CSS/Javascript into a google site with less restrictions that the edit source feature.