# Custom CSS/JS for Google Sites

Tags: javascript, css, web, customization, google-sites

The new Google Sites service is amazing, a website (mostly static with some Google services) can be created with just 1 file in Google Drive.

However, it has no direct UI to customise CSS or to add additional JS.

**Anyone with a work-around for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is not possible. I gave it a spin, but no Luck.

There are multiple questions on SO about this, and they all lead to the documentation, which doesn't give us any more information:

[Create my own Google site template Using my own CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086330/create-my-own-google-site-template-using-my-own-css)

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/98216?hl=en&visit_id=637177843384493895-752760820&rd=2

Answer (score 1):

You can make a page that is 100% HTML/CSS. However, it looks like you can not mix and match.